# C# Task memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, task

I have a memory leak issue with a Task object in C#.

This code will give me the memory leak:

```
 Task task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                result = analysis.InspectImageAsync(arg1, arg2);
            });

    await task;



    task.ContinueWith( (thisTask) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("kill");
                thisTask.Dispose();
                thisTask = null;
                GC.Collect();
            });
```

If I run it without the Task.Run():

```
result = analysis.InspectImageAsync(arg1, arg2);
```

everything works great and my memory is flat flat flat (no leaks!)... but I need this to be async.

Comment: Using GC.Collect is not smart - when seeing InspectImage I am wondering if you are disposing everything. Are you using "using"?

Comment: I've tried, but I can't figure out how to use "using" in this context.  I've also played around with "try" and then "finally"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx gives a good idea - just collect all your disposable ressources in one clause at the beginning and it is clean.

Comment: I just tried:    using(Task task = Task.Run(() =>  {  result = analysis.InspectImageAsync(arg1, arg2); }) )
            {
                await task;
            }                                    the syntax worked... but the memory leak is still there.  I'm getting the impression that calling .Dispose() on a Task is simply not doing anything

Comment: care to show us `InspectImageAsync` implementation?

Comment: For the task itself is not neccessary to call disposing - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx. I suspect that you use ressources requiring disposing in InspectImageAsync .

Comment: hmm.. I was definitely thinking that as well... but when I run  result = analysis.InspectImageAsync(arg1, arg2) without setting it to an async task I get no memory leaks.  If there was something within InspectImageAsync not getting cleaned up, it would show itself.  I suspect that by adding the whole thing to background threads... those threads aren't getting cleaned before the next iteration of a loop happens.  (By the way there is a higher loop going on that this is all under)

Comment: Are you encountering this issue 'in the wild' or only in visual studio with a debugger attached? I had a similar problem with MQTT library, where Visual studio debugger reported always increasing memory usage. The profiler told me that it was thousands of tasks, but no such behavior was observed when the app was operating by itself.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to dispose the task? I'm wondering if you're undercutting the `analysis` instance so that it cannot properly clean itself up. That's the only thing that stares out at me from the code snippets that's currently on this post.

Comment: @rikkitikkitumbo Have you figured out this issue? I have the same problem and the memory is slowly creeping up. Tasks are being completed but memory isnt decreasing

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem.
are you using memory streams?

in my case,

I put a 5MB image in the memorystream and used it, but there is no real memory leak, but it caused an out of memory error.

If it is only for 64bit, it will be the same as 32bit when opened through Visual Studio.
In debug mode, it is the same as the 32-bit environment, so it appears a little faster, and in the release mode, it is a 64-bit environment, so it occurs a little later.

If the memory continues to increase in the task manager, you should think about Dispose, but if an out-of-memory error occurs, you should check whether an object that needs to be assigned consecutive addresses is used.

Answer (score -1):

Use task.Dispose(), to dispose the memory used by the task